# What's Wrong With This Script?

Tags: php, html, forms, web, contacts

I have a website, and at the bottom, I have a "Contact Us" section. It sends the email, but when I check it in my email, it shows up in Spam. It thinks it has an empty message from an empty email. Here's the HTML:

```
Apply:
                        <form action ="contact2.php" method "post">
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"name ="cf_name" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control"name = 'cf_email' placeholder="Email Addres" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name = 'cf_message' placeholder="Why should we pick you?" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And here's the PHP:

```
 <?php
 $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
 $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
 $field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

 $mail_to = 'staff@goldenmistgames.com';
 $subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

 $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
 $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
 $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

 $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

 $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

 if ($mail_status) { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'contact_page.html';
 </script>
 <?php
 }
 else { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-   help.com');
    window.location = 'contact_page.html';
 </script>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple that the PHP-Mail function is not using a well configured SMTP Server.

Nowadays Email-Clients and Servers perform massive checks on the emails sending server, like Reverse-DNS-Lookups, Graylisting and whatevs. All this tests will fail with the php mail() function. If you are using a dynamic ip, its even worse.

Use the PHPMailer-Class and configure it to use smtp-auth along with a well configured, dedicated SMTP Server (either a local one, or a remote one) and your problems are gone.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check this out in a little bit.